# SQL How to add multiple attributes to group by function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am using Oracle SQL ad want to write a query that will display the customer(s) details that referred the maximum number of customers. There can be more than one customer (if the max number of referrals for each customer are equal).

In a `CUSTOMER` table containing `CUS_ID, CUS_NAME, CUS_REFERRED` I can get the `CUS_REFERRED` and `COUNT(CUST_REFERRED)` using:

```
   select  CUST_REFERRED, count(CUST_REFERRED)
   from CUSTOMER 
   group by CUST_REFERRED
   having count(CUST_REFERRED) = (select max(MYCOUNT) 
   from (select cust_referred, 
           count(CUST_REFERRED) MYCOUNT 
           from CUSTOMER 
           group by CUST_REFERRED));
```

**Sample data:**

```
Cust_Num        Cust_FName         Cust_Referred
------------------------------------------------
1000            Patricia           (null)
1001            Jim                1000
1002            Zoe                1003
1003            John               (null)
1004            Marie              1003
1005            Anthony            1002
1006            Jodee              1003
```

**Current output:**

```
CUST_REFERRED   COUNT(C.CUST_REFERRED) 
-------------   ---------------------- 
1003            3
```

**Desired output:**

```
CUST_FNAME  CUST_REFERRED   COUNT(C.CUST_REFERRED) 
----------  -------------   ---------------------- 
John        1003            3
```

Where John is customer 1003 and has the made the most referrals (3). If another person (say Jack) had also made 3 referrals, he would also be listed.

However, whenever I try and add in `CUS_FNAME` - I get 'no rows returned' (if in the main select query) or a list of customers with 1 referral (in the nested select query).

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Oracle 12c:

```
select c.cust_num, c.cust_fname, cr.cnt
from customer c
join
(
  select cust_referred, count(*) as cnt
  from customer
  group by cust_referred
  order by count(*) desc
  fetch first row with ties
) cr on cr.cust_referred = c.cust_num;
```

In older versions:

```
select c.cust_num, c.cust_fname, cr.cnt
from customer c
join
(
  select
    cust_referred,
    count(*) as cnt,
    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from customer
  group by cust_referred
) cr on cr.cust_referred = c.cust_num and cr.rnk = 1;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa5875f649943cacaa3e03b86ebe3cf4

Comment: Both return no rows selected (I am using Version 18.4)

Comment: Then you made some mistake. I've added a demo showing that both queries work.

Comment: Thanks - your fiddle works and when I replicate it in my database it works, so I will mark it as the answer. However, for some reason, it does not work on my DB Customer table.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select cust_referred, cnt
from (select cust_referred, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*)) as seqnum
      from customer
      group by cust_referred
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want more information about the customer, then you can join this back to the `customer` table.

Comment: Thanks, your query returns a list of non-max customers. 
My query returns one customer who made the most referrals, but I can't bring up more results for that customer. My return values:
`CUST_REFERRED  COUNT(C.CUST_REFERRED)
-------------                   ----------------------
         1003                      3`

Customer 1003 details required to add to query